# How to change the order of advanced custom form? - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

im trying to change the order in which appear the groups fields, for example, i have a group field named "Header" but it appears at the end of the page editor, and the other groups field appears in different order that i want, so i want to change the order for have the same order that is presented in the page, in the html.

Thank for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Order No. works but not always work, in my case i had to change the order directly en the database. Checking the id post of the custom fields and order this in the table wp_usermeta in the meta-box-order

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `Order No.` for each field group. This is found on each field group edit page at the bottom. If you want the "header" first assign it `0` and then the subsequent groups something higher.

> **Order No.** Field groups are created in order from lowest to highest